# Variable concatenation in wrong order

Tags: string, powershell, filepath

I have the following:

```
function createFolder($folderName, $curPath)
{
    $dest = $curPath + $folderName
    write-host "Path is : " + $dest
    # code to mess around with files etc
}
```

When I run this it gives me the following output:

```
Path is : + Test_Folder C:\Users\Me
```

Is there something I'm missing with the `+` operator, or a join/concat method that is meant for this kind of function? What is the correct way to create/concat/manipulate paths in PowerShell (I've just started using this to automate some cleanup tasks on my desktop).

EDIT: In case it makes a difference, this is what I see when I run the version command:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> version
BladeLogic Network Shell 8.2.01.273 (Release) [May 12 2012 21:56:02]
Copyright (C) 1996-2012 BladeLogic Inc.
```

Also, I'm on a work computer with no administrative privileges.

I tried:

```
$currentPath = "C:\Users\n0223270\Downloads"
$test = "test"
createFolder($test, $currentPath)

function createFolder($folderName, $curPath)
{
    $dest = join-path -path $curPath -childpath $folderName
    Write-Host $dest   
}
```

This was the following error:

```
Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:4 char:28
+     $dest = join-path -path <<<<  $curPath -childpath $folderName
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
```

Comment: Try using the Join-Path cmdlet instead of string concatenation.

Comment: What's `$curPath`? What's `$folderName`? `+` isn't string concat, you can just put variables in a string or use `-f` to format variables into a string (which is usually better).

Comment: $curPath is the current working directory, so in the above example: $curPath = "C:\Users\Me" and $folderName is the name of a folder to be created if it doesn't exist and used as the destination for a copy and paste job later on in the function, in the above: $folderName = "Test_Folder"

Comment: @EBGreen I tried the Join-Path cmdlet, updated question with the results

Comment: You're using parens and commas to call a powerShell function.  Try `createFolder $test $currentPath`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `createFolder($test, $currentPath)`

This isn't how you call a Powershell function.  This is passing the first parameter as an array of two strings.  The second parameter would be null because it's not specified and there's no default.

Try:

```
createFolder $test $currentPath
```

Comment: Ok that worked just fine, thanks. Still trying to migrate from a Java background to powershell scripting

Comment: @jbailie1991 It's definitely non-obvious if you haven't encountered it before because the language is very C-like.  IMX, the more you use it the more you'll use named parameters with the `param()` construct instead of the C-like function definition.  See the `Get-Help about_Functions*` articles.